# iOS: Crash when keyboard is used...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

**Pretty simple bug:**

Pressing any key on my Mac's keyboard causes an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error to occur when running an app on the simulator. Unless I'm entering data into a text field that is, where it works fine.

-

Not sure if this is a bug in my app, or somewhere else. If by some chance, someone was using a bluetooth keyboard with my app, then I don't exactly want it crashing willy nilly... small chance I know, but I'd still rather fix it if it's a bug. I've enabled zombies - doesn't tell me anything about where the crash is occurring, and the app still crashes.

Any thoughts or answers are much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Please post your code if possible

Comment: @Jennis - it seems to happen from almost anywhere in my app. Makes posting the code a bit harder :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning off "Auto-Correction" in the simulator keyboard settings fixed this issue for me.

Screenshot of Keyboard Settings in Simulator:

[image]

Seems there are still bugs with the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This bug is usually attributed to trying to access an instance that has already been released. Check your instances, anything that you allocated, released, and then you are trying to access. It may not even be connected to the keyboard, but maybe a delegate method. Post some code so we can have a better idea of it. For example, the code for the view controller that is running at the time of the crash.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. I'm aware of what the crash message means, but given that it happens anywhere in the app and I can't get the crash point to be shown with zombies/guard malloc, I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your app with "`Guard Malloc"` on. You find this setting when you go to

> Manage Scheme -> Run app (on the left side) -> diagnostic (on the top
>   lashes) -> under Memeory management.

This will show you the crash point where it happens and you should be able to find the reason much more easily

Comment: Thanks! I've done this - but unfortunately it still doesn't show where the crash happens. Wondering if this is a sign that maybe it's a bug in the simulator rather than with my app?